# Help with SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns function

Tags: sharepoint-designer, spservices

I'm busy working on a form that requires a cascading relationship between two fields/dropdown columns.

Field 1 - '**Country**' and has is a lookup column of a list of **Countries**.
[image]

Field 2 - '**Region**' and is a lookup column of a list of '**Regions**' which is a list of regionsrelated to a 'Country' via a lookup column.

[image]

My use case here is, of course, depending on what I select in the 'Country' field, I want to then update the 'Regions' field to only show the Regions related to the selected country.

I have followed the following tutorial here - http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation
(You will notice I am not including the 'States' column, as I dont need this 3rd level.)

I have followed the example almost to the T, but when I run it I get the following error

[image]

I am struggling to understand or figure out where the 'connection' is breaking in the Regions list. My column names all seem to be correct.. :-/

Any advice?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Fount the problem. :) Turns out there was a descrepency between the tutorial code and the associated instructions during setting it up.
The supplied code to hook up the cascading dropdowns based on the created lists mentioned a CAML query which was referencing a field which didnt exist. Removed the CAML code and all was well.

Thanks for the reply though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fount the problem. :)

Turns out there was a descrepency between the tutorial code and the associated instructions during setting it up. The supplied code to hook up the cascading dropdowns based on the created lists mentioned a CAML query which was referencing a field which didnt exist.

Removed the CAML code and all was well.